# PyCharm 2017.1, No module named 'kivy'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, kivy, anaconda

I could use (troubleshooting)help with getting Kivy imported in PyCharm. I am using:

- Anaconda with Python 3 on 64-bit Windows 10 Pro
- PyCharm 2017.1
- Packages: NumPy, SciPy, BeautifulSoup, Pandas, Scrapy, Pattern, NetworkX, NLTK, scikit-learn, Selenium

I have installed Kivy following the instructions at https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation

As evident from the screen shot, no errors occurred.

[image]

Still, when I run "import kivy"  from PyCharm I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'".

I ran through the installation with someone on the #kivy channel and was assured that kivy is successfully installed.

When I pass import kivy; print(kivy.**file**) to the interpreter (opened from the CMD command line), I get returned among others:

```
C:\Users\Steve\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py
```

Someone on #kivy suggested I check where PyCharm looks for kivy. How do I figure that out?

I'd appreciate any suggestions to identify the problem / resolve my issue.

Comment: I started the python interpreter from the command prompt and

Comment: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration#pycharm

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the installation of Kivy went fine. The problem turned out to be that I had to select the correct (updated) interpreter in the PyCharm settings.